# Select an item in a dropdownlist in a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview which is databound by a list of objects.
In the listview, i have a dropdownlist on each item. Which is filled in the .._itemcreated event.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListList" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ListItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAccountManagers" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Depending on which item, i have to set the selectedvalue of the dropdown. But how do I do this?

How do I access the current items values in the itemcreated event?

Comment: `ItemCreated` event is fired before the item is data-bound. Thus no data is still in the listview item or the controls nested inside it. In `ItemDataBound` all is available.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
ddlAccountManagers.SelectedValue="value you want to be selected"
```

In the list of objects you have, I suppose that each object will be associated with an AccountManager. An AccoutManager logically would have an id, that will distinguish him/her from the rest of account managers. Then you have to put this value as the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to fill the dropdownlist, I assume you already have access to it.

```
ddlAccountManagers.Items.FindByText("TextToSelect").Selected = True
```

or

```
ddlAccountManagers.Items.FindByValue("ValueToSelect").Selected = True
```